# Flutter GridTile can be triggered with tap?

Tags: gridview, dart, flutter

I have created a flutter app and used the image-picker to get images to the center as a gridView with looping the image array with grid tiles.Is it possible to trigger the gridTile when it is tapped?
Below is the code from the main.dart for getting the image adding it to an array and to a grid view.

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
int _counter = 0;
File _imageFile;
List<File> _imageList=[];

getImage() async {
var _fileName = await ImagePicker.pickImage();
setState(() {
  _imageFile = _fileName;
  _imageList.add(_imageFile);
});
}

 removeImage(int index){
  setState((){
  _imageList.removeAt(index);
});
}
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {

 return new Scaffold(
  appBar: new AppBar(

    title: new Text(widget.title),
  ),
  body: new Center(

    child:_imageList.length == 0
        ? new Text('No image selected.')
        :new GridView.count(
        crossAxisCount: 4,
        childAspectRatio: 1.0,
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
        mainAxisSpacing: 4.0,
        crossAxisSpacing: 4.0,
        children: _imageList.map((File file) {
          return new GridTile(

              child: new Image.file(file, fit: BoxFit.cover,));

        }).toList()),
  ),

  floatingActionButton: new FloatingActionButton(
    onPressed:getImage,
    tooltip: 'Pick Image',
    child: new Icon(Icons.add_a_photo),
  ),
);
}
}
```

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You can just wrap the `GridTile` in an `InkResponse` or `GestureDetector` and pass a function to be invoked when clicked

Example:

```
// Function to be called on click
void _onTileClicked(int index){
  debugPrint("You tapped on item $index");
}

// Get grid tiles
List<Widget> _getTiles(List<File> iconList) {
  final List<Widget> tiles = <Widget>[];
  for (int i = 0; i < iconList.length; i++) {
    tiles.add(new GridTile(
        child: new InkResponse(
      enableFeedback: true,
      child: new Image.file(iconList[i], fit: BoxFit.cover,),
      onTap: () => _onTileClicked(i),
    )));
  }
  return tiles;
}


// GridView
new GridView.count(
  crossAxisCount: 4,
  childAspectRatio: 1.0,
  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
  mainAxisSpacing: 4.0,
  crossAxisSpacing: 4.0,
  children: _getTiles(_imageList),
)
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 8):

You can also work with grid builder

```
child: new GridView.builder(
          itemCount: 20,
          gridDelegate: new SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
              crossAxisCount: 2),
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            return new Card(
              child: new InkResponse(
                 child: Image.asset('assets/whats-best-for-your-app-objective-cswift.jpg'),
                onTap: (){
                  print(index);
                },
              ),
            );
          }),
```