# How to get GridTile position in GridView flutter?

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-layout

I'm using GridTile to create each item in a GridView. Each item is created dynamically from the data list. I need to find out which item is clicked by either getting the key or index. Please, anyone, suggest a method?

This is my code,

```
 new GridView.count(
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    primary: false,
                    childAspectRatio: 2.0,
                    crossAxisCount: 3,
                    mainAxisSpacing: 10.0,
                    children: _kCategoryTiles.map((_FilterItemTile item) {
                      return new GridTile(
                        child: new Container(
                          alignment: Alignment.center,
                          decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                            shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
                            borderRadius: new BorderRadius.all(
                                new Radius.elliptical(10.0, 20.0)),
                            border: new Border.all(
                              color: const Color(0xFF33b17c),
                            ),
                          ),
                          margin: new EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                          child: new Text(
                            item.itemName,
                            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                            style: new TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.black,
                              fontSize: 12.0,
                              fontFamily: 'helvetica_neue_medium',
                              letterSpacing: 0.59,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      );
                    }).toList(),
                  )
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Concise solution with `new GridTile(child: new InkResponse(onTap: () => _onTileClicked(i), ..))` , here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/49104954/2162226

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your GridTile in a [FlatButton](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/FlatButton-class.html) which gives you the `onPressed` property. In there you can access your `_FilterItemTile item`:

```
return new GridView.count(
    shrinkWrap: true,
    primary: false,
    childAspectRatio: 2.0,
    crossAxisCount: 3,
    mainAxisSpacing: 10.0,
    children: _kCategoryTiles.map((_FilterItemTile item) {
        return new FlatButton(
    onPressed: () {
        // add code here
        print(item);
        someFunction(item);
    },
    child: new GridTile(
        child: new Container(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            decoration: new BoxDecoration(
            shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
            borderRadius: new BorderRadius.all(
                new Radius.elliptical(10.0, 20.0)),
            border: new Border.all(
                color: const Color(0xFF33b17c),
            ),
            ),
            margin: new EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
            child: new Text(
            item.itemName,
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            style: new TextStyle(
                color: Colors.black,
                fontSize: 12.0,
                fontFamily: 'helvetica_neue_medium',
                letterSpacing: 0.59,
            ),
            ),
        ),
        );
        )
    }).toList(),
),
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. but  I want the item position or index value.

Comment: Sorry, edited it wrong. I edited it again where the GridTile is wrapped by the FlatButton. Now you can access the item on the press of one GridTile.

Comment: With position you mean the index value ( in your case _FilterItemTile item )? Just include it in the onPressed with `item`.

Comment: I added it. Basically it's just `yourFunction(item)`

Comment: it gives the item but i want the gridTile position(an integer value) in that grid view.

Comment: #RMR did you ever solve your problem? I have the samw one.

Comment: I don't think you answered OP's question. I believe that he was asking how to access a specific GridTile in a GridView. Since a GridView is a method of displaying a List, say "myList", the way to access the third tile appears to be myList[2]. If the access causes a change to the contents of the List item (i.e., myList[2]), then some sort of setState() is required to revise the GridView.